# How to execute an exploit without user interaction?

Tags: malware, virus, metasploit

Is there an existing exploit, virus or malware that doesn't need any user interaction? 
In metasploit for example.
No link to clicked, no pdf to open , no vba or exe to execute by the victim.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, certainly.  Malware that affects network accessible services very rarely require user interaction.   A worm such as SQL Slammer is a prime example, which propagated across the Internet looking for exposed SQL Servers that had a blank password for the sa account.

Client machines may also expose vulnerable services, but even if they don't, they can still be infected without specific user interaction through mechanisms such as drive-by-downloads, where a malicious website or component (like an ad from an infected ad network) uses a vulnerability in a browser or browser plugin to escape the sandbox and silently install.